# Logging when and how a PHP file is used in a web app

Tags: php, logging, get, freebsd

I have a php web application that I am doing some testing on.  This application is running on a Freebsd host. In the application directory, I have several .php files that I am not sure what/when they are used. Is there a way it log when this .php file is accessed by the application, and what arguments are passed to it, when it is used?

Comment: can you look through the source of the primary file and look for those file names?

Comment: Your best bet is to add a line to write a note in a log file when each file is run.

Comment: If the scripts are web accessible and run directly, that would appear in the access log for the web server. Get params will be logged, but you would not see cookies or posts.  If it is being included/required etc, no, but you could easily add custom logging.  Really depends what is in the script(s) in question.

Comment: [debug_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) could be helpful.  Just add a call to that in the files/functions you are curious about and log its result to a file.

Comment: xdebug will give you full traces, albeit it makes the app run slower... but I guess, when a file is opened for reading by the PHP interpreter, its last access time will change on the filesystem, which you can look up with the 'stat' unix command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can just put an error_log() call at the beginning of each file, assuming that you have accessing to whatever logs they will be written to (typically webserver error logs).

```
$error_msg = 'File: ' . __FILE__ . ' Request: ' . var_export($_REQUEST, true);
error_log($error_msg);
```

That will log the file being accessed, and and export of the Request superglobal so you know what is in GET, POST, and COOKIE.

Answer (score 0):

The debug_backtrace or debug_print_backtrace will give you everything you need, including what files and functions were loaded before so you can discover the entire call/load path.